Is There Solution To Solve My Unique Case on VirtualizedList Problem
I got this warning:  VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update - make sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate, etc. {"contentLength": 8832, "dt": 1939, "prevDt": 1122}
code 1
import React, { useMemo } from 'react';

const Verse = React.memo(({ coord, verse, color }) => (
  <div key={coord.key} style={{position: 'absolute', top: `${coord.top}%`, right: `${coord.right}%`, width: `${coord.width}%`, height: `${coord.height}%`, backgroundColor: color}}>
    {verse}
  </div>
));

const renderItem = (coord, verse, color) => <Verse coord={coord} verse={verse} color={color} />;

const MushafPage = React.memo(({ pageData, parts = 2 }) => {
  const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet', 'pink']; // Array of colors

  // Calculate the total height of all verses
  const totalHeight = useMemo(() => pageData.reduce((total, item) => total + item.coord.reduce((totalCoord, coord) => totalCoord + coord.top + coord.height, 0), 0), [pageData]);

  // Calculate the height of each part
  const partHeight = totalHeight / parts;

  // Initialize the current part and its height
  let currentPart = 0;
  let currentHeight = 0;

  return (
    <div>
      {pageData.map((item) => {
        return item.coord.map((coord, index) => {
          // Add the height of the current item to the current height
          currentHeight += coord.top + coord.height;

          // If the current height exceeds the part height, move to the next part
          if (currentHeight > partHeight) {
            currentPart++;
            currentHeight -= partHeight; // Subtract the partHeight from the currentHeight
          }

          // Choose a color based on the current part
          const color = colors[currentPart % colors.length];

          return renderItem(coord, item.verse, color);
        });
      })}
    </div>
  );
});

export default MushafPage;

The code above will be imported into the this file code ,
code 2:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import MushafPage from '../../components/MushafPage';

// Import JSON files
import data1 from '../../assets/mushaf/juz30/content/1.json';
import data2 from '../../assets/mushaf/juz30/content/2.json';
import data3 from '../../assets/mushaf/juz30/content/3.json';
import data4 from '../../assets/mushaf/juz30/content/4.json';

function Block() {
  const [pageData, setPageData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Combine all JSON data into one array
    const allData = [data1, data2, data3, data4];

    setPageData(allData.flat());
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="Block">
      {pageData.map((data, index) => <MushafPage key={index} pageData={data} parts={2} />)}
    </div>
  );
}

export default React.memo(Block);

then in it there are .json files which are the basis for dividing the pages, like this
code 3:
[
  {
    "key": "581-1",
    "verse": "78:1",
    "coord": [
      {
        "key": "78:1:1",
        "top": 21.6,
        "right": 2.2,
        "width": 26.1,
        "height": 4.7
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "581-2",
    "verse": "78:2",
    "coord": [
      {
        "key": "78:2:1",
        "top": 21.6,
        "right": 28.4,
        "width": 28.1,
        "height": 4.7
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "581-3",
    "verse": "78:3",
    "coord": [
      {
        "key": "78:3:1",
        "top": 21.6,
        "right": 56.75,
        "width": 36.2,
        "height": 4.7
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "581-4",
    "verse": "78:4",
    "coord": [
      {
        "key": "78:4:1",
        "top": 26.7,
        "right": 2.2,
        "width": 26.1,
        "height": 4.7
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "581-5",
    "verse": "78:5",
    "coord": [
      {
        "key": "78:5:1",
        "top": 26.7,
        "right": 28.75,
        "width": 28.6,
        "height": 4.7
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "581-6",
    "verse": "78:6",
    "coord": [
      {
        "key": "78:6:1",
        "top": 26.7,
        "right": 57.5,
        "width": 36.1,
        "height": 4.7
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "581-7",
    "verse": "78:7",
    "coord": [
      {
        "key": "78:7:1",
        "top": 31.8,
        "right": 2.2,
        "width": 27.1,
        "height": 4.7
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "581-8",
    "verse": "78:8",
    "coord": [
      {
        "key": "78:8:1",
        "top": 31.8,
        "right": 31,
        "width": 30.1,
        "height": 4.7
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "581-9",
    "verse": "78:9",
    "coord": [
      {
        "key": "78:9:1",
        "top": 31.8,
        "right": 61.75,
        "width": 32,
        "height": 4.7
      },
      {
        "key": "78:9:2",
        "top": 36.9,
        "right": 2.2,
        "width": 5.1,
        "height": 4.7
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "581-10",
    "verse": "78:10",
    "coord": [
      {
        "key": "78:10:1",
        "top": 36.9,
        "right": 7.2,
        "width": 35.6,
        "height": 4.7
      }
    ]    
  },
  {
    "key": "581-11",
    "verse": "78:11",
    "coord": [
      {
        "key": "78:11:1",
        "top": 36.9,
        "right": 42.9,
        "width": 39.1,
        "height": 4.7
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "581-12",
    "verse": "78:12",
    "coord": [
      {
        "key": "78:12:1",
        "top": 36.9,
        "right": 82.25,
        "width": 11.5,
        "height": 4.7
      },
      {
        "key": "78:12:2",
        "top": 42.05,
        "right": 2.2,
        "width": 36.6,
        "height": 4.7
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "581-13",
    "verse": "78:13",
    "coord": [
      {
        "key": "78:13:1",
        "top": 42.05,
        "right": 40,
        "width": 40.6,
        "height": 4.7
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "581-14",
    "verse": "78:14",
    "coord": [
      {
        "key": "78:14:1",
        "top": 42.05,
        "right": 82,
        "width": 11.5,
        "height": 4.7
      },
      {
        "key": "78:14:2",
        "top": 47.15,
        "right": 2.2,
        "width": 40.1,
        "height": 4.7
      }
    ],
    "covers": {
      "firstWord": [
        {
          "key": "78:14:1",
          "top": 47.15,
          "right": 2.2,
          "width": 35,
          "height": 4.7
        }
      ],
      "invisible": [
        {
          "key": "78:14:1",
          "top": 42.05,
          "right": 82,
          "width": 11.5,
          "height": 4.7
        },
        {
          "key": "78:14:2",
          "top": 47.15,
          "right": 2.2,
          "width": 35,
          "height": 4.7
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "581-15",
    "verse": "78:15",
    "coord": [
      {
        "key": "78:15:1",
        "top": 47.15,
        "right": 42.47,
        "width": 38.1,
        "height": 4.7
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "581-16",
    "verse": "78:16",
    "coord": [
      {
        "key": "78:16:1",
        "top": 47.15,
        "right": 81.5,
        "width": 12,
        "height": 4.7
      },
      {
        "key": "78:16:2",
        "top": 52.35,
        "right": 2.2,
        "width": 14.6,
        "height": 4.7
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "581-17",
    "verse": "78:17",
    "coord": [
      {
        "key": "78:17:1",
        "top": 52.35,
        "right": 17.5,
        "width": 45.1,
        "height": 4.7
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "581-18",
    "verse": "78:18",
    "coord": [
      {
        "key": "78:18:1",
        "top": 52.35,
        "right": 62.75,
        "width": 30,
        "height": 4.7
      },
      {
        "key": "78:18:2",
        "top": 57.45,
        "right": 2.2,
        "width": 24.6,
        "height": 4.7
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "581-19",
    "verse": "78:19",
    "coord": [
      {
        "key": "78:19:1",
        "top": 57.45,
        "right": 27.3,
        "width": 50.1,
        "height": 4.7
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "581-20",
    "verse": "78:20",
    "coord": [
      {
        "key": "78:20:1",
        "top": 57.45,
        "right": 77.75,
        "width": 15.5,
        "height": 4.7
      },
      {
        "key": "78:20:2",
        "top": 62.55,
        "right": 2.2,
        "width": 36.1,
        "height": 4.7
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "581-21",
    "verse": "78:21",
    "coord": [
      {
        "key": "78:21:1",
        "top": 62.55,
        "right": 39,
        "width": 39.85,
        "height": 4.7
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "581-22",
    "verse": "78:22",
    "coord": [
      {
        "key": "78:22:1",
        "top": 62.55,
        "right": 78.85,
        "width": 14.75,
        "height": 4.7
      },
      {
        "key": "78:22:2",
        "top": 67.65,
        "right": 2.2,
        "width": 13.85,
        "height": 4.7
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "581-23",
    "verse": "78:23",
    "coord": [
      {
        "key": "78:23:1",
        "top": 67.7,
        "right": 16.25,
        "width": 33.6,
        "height": 4.7
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "581-24",
    "verse": "78:24",
    "coord": [
      {
        "key": "78:24:1",
        "top": 67.7,
        "right": 50,
        "width": 43.5,
        "height": 4.7
      },
      {
        "key": "78:24:2",
        "top": 72.85,
        "right": 2.2,
        "width": 5.1,
        "height": 4.7
      }
    ]  },
  {
    "key": "581-25",
    "verse": "78:25",
    "coord": [
      {
        "key": "78:25:1",
        "top": 72.85,
        "right": 7.4,
        "width": 37.6,
        "height": 4.7
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "581-26",
    "verse": "78:26",
    "coord": [
      {
        "key": "78:26:1",
        "top": 72.85,
        "right": 45,
        "width": 27.6,
        "height": 4.7
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "581-27",
    "verse": "78:27",
    "coord": [
      {
        "key": "78:27:1",
        "top": 72.85,
        "right": 73,
        "width": 20,
        "height": 4.7
      },
      {
        "key": "78:27:2",
        "top": 77.95,
        "right": 2.2,
        "width": 32.6,
        "height": 4.7
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "581-28",
    "verse": "78:28",
    "coord": [
      {
        "key": "78:28:1",
        "top": 77.95,
        "right": 34.9,
        "width": 43.1,
        "height": 4.7
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "581-29",
    "verse": "78:29",
    "coord": [
      {
        "key": "78:29:1",
        "top": 77.95,
        "right": 78,
        "width": 15.5,
        "height": 4.7
      },
      {
        "key": "78:29:2",
        "top": 83.05,
        "right": 2.2,
        "width": 31.1,
        "height": 4.7
      }
    ],
    "covers": {
      "firstWord": [
        {
          "key": "78:29:1",
          "top": 77.95,
          "right": 85.25,
          "width": 8.25,
          "height": 4.7
        },
        {
          "key": "78:29:2",
          "top": 83.05,
          "right": 2.2,
          "width": 26,
          "height": 4.7
        }
      ]
  },
  {
    "key": "581-30",
    "verse": "78:30",
    "coord": [
      {
        "key": "78:30:1",
        "top": 83.05,
        "right": 33.75,
        "width": 59.1,
        "height": 4.95
      }
    ]
  }
]


The context is that I want to divide a manuscript page into several parts (2-8 parts) using Code 1, which applies color. After that, I use Code 2 to import Code 1, enabling it to be applied to five .json files. These files contain coordinate image data for the start and end of each paragraph. Code 3 refers to the original .json file, which contains the coordinates of each item and the length of the paragraph. In the original implementation, there were ten .json files
I have tried many times to optimize my code but the program still gives the same warning, namely: VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update - make sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate, etc. {"contentLength": 8832, "dt": 1939, "prevDt": 1122}
